# Как получить значение переменной из другого класса?

Tags: c#, variable

Допустим, у меня есть класс, в котором пользователь может ввести значение

```
class DogStats
{
    static public void Stats(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Write("Write your dog's weight(in kg): \n");
        double weight = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
    }
}
```

Каким образом мне получить это значение в другом классе? К примеру, в такой конструкции:

```
class DogEat
{
    static public void DogEating()
    {


        Console.WriteLine("Do you want to feed your dog 3 times?");
        string choose = Console.ReadLine();
        switch (choose)
        {
            case "Y": //**!HERE!**

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/3.1.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У Вас в коде используются статические методы. Это удобно, с точки зрения того, что не нужно создавать экземпляр класса при вызове такого метода - но тогда логично было бы использовать вообще статические классы.

В остальном - использование статических методов (и классов) считается не совсем хорошей практикой, по ряду причин, из которых мне кажутся важными две: статические классы не очень хорошо подходят для тестирования, и вообще подвержены сайд-эффектам и 2) они не могут имплементировать интерфейсы.

Но на самом деле у вас есть другая проблема: у Вас метод  класс DogStats запрашивает у пользователя некий ввод, но не сохраняет введенное значение.

Обычно для таких вещей в классах создают поля. То есть, есть поле - "хранитель данных", есть метод - "код, который данные спросит у пользователя".

Поля могут быть приватными, могут быть - и это очень здорово - объявлены как `{get; private set;}` - это даёт возможность внутри класса работать с этим полем, а "снаружи" - только читать его.

С этими замечаниями задача становится решаемой, путём совсем небольшой модификации кода:

```
   class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {

            DogEat.DogEating();

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    class DogStats {
        
        public static double Weight { get; private set; }
        public static void Stats() {
            Console.Write("Write your dog's weight(in kg): \n");
            Weight = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        }
    }

    class DogEat {
        public static void DogEating() {


            Console.WriteLine("Do you want to feed your dog 3 times?");
            string choose = Console.ReadLine();
            switch (choose) {
                case "Y": 
                    DogStats.Stats();
                    break;
                case "N":
                    break;
            }

            Console.WriteLine($"Your dog's weight: {DogStats.Weight}");
        }
    }
```

Вывод программы тогда будет примерно слеующим:

```
    Do you want to feed your dog 3 times?
    Y
    Write your dog's weight(in kg):
    20
    Your dog's weight: 20
```

Если у Вас есть вопросы - пишите в комментариях, а вообще из серьезного чтива по C# я бы посоветовал книжку автора Албахари ("Справочник. Полное описание языка") - по этой фамилии она легко гуглится, и перевод одного из изданий, не слишком устаревшего, есть на русском.

Успехов Вам!

Comment: Здесь можно было просто вызвать метод с аргументом. И выкинуть статику.